# How to count objects in videos

Tags: python, video, deep-learning, opticalflow

In general, is there any "best practise" on how to use videos as input of deep learning models? How can we annotate video in the most efficient way?

Also, I have some videos with ducks walking through a passage. I want to count the number of grey-duck and the number of yellow-duck passing through the passage. A duck can pass directly through (easiest case), or can stay in the passage for a while and pass through, or can go half the passage and go back the other direction (in this case it should not be counted).

I plan to use Mask-RCNN to segment ducks in each frame and then to look at the masks from frame i and masks from frame i+1 and make rules to count the number of different ducks that truly pass the passage.
This does not seems optimal to me.

Any ideas/help/hints?

Comment: I think "optical flow" algorithm is the best method for movement tracking in video

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess it depends on the video, but a good option was to

1. **Annotate** some 'not to similar frames' with: http://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~vgg/software/via/
2. Use a model like **YOLO** or **Mask-RCNN** to find bounding box over each objects and classfiy them. Or use Optical flow algorithm. **Optical flow** algorithm is also an option instead of using deep learning, but I finally decided not to use it due to several possible outcome which made it from my point of view less automatic: *object that moves, stop and restart moving would require special attention *objects which are of one main color might be split into two pieces (middle pixels might be saw as not moving) *group of object passing together will probably be saw as one object
3. Then using **tracking algorithm** you will be able to give a specific ID to each object, and hence to count when they pass a certain line.